# implementacion de un dropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy realizando dropDownList en cascada pero al momento de desplegarlo solo el primero muestra la informacion y al seleccionar algun elemento se supone el segundo actualizaria la lista pero no lo hace el cogido compila lo he revisado por horas y no encuentro la falla, este es el script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#IdDepartamento").change(function () {
            //Se limpia el contenido del dropdownlist
            $("#IdMunicipio").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                //Llamado al metodo en el controlador
                url: '@Url.Action("GetStateByIdDepartartamento", "municipio")',
                dataType: 'json',
                //Parametros que se envian al metodo del controlador
                data: { IdDepartamento: $("#IdDepartamento").val() },
                //En caso de resultado exitoso
                success: function (municipio) {
                    if (municipio.length == 0) {
                        $("#IdMunicipio").append('<option value=""></option>');
                    }
                    else {
                        //Se agrega el elemento vacio para poder desplegar que seleccione una opcion
                        $("#IdMunicipio").append('<option value=""></option>');
                        $.each(municipio, function (i, municipio) {
                            $("#IdMunicipio").append('<option value="' + municipio.Value + '">' +
                                municipio.Text + '</option>');
                        });
                    }
                    //Recargar el plugin para que tenga la funcionalidad del componente
                    $("#IdMunicipio").select2({ placeholder: "Seleccione Municipio", width: "20%" });
                },
                //Mensaje de error en caso de fallo
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
                }
            });
            return false;
        })          
    });
</script>
```

y este es el controlador

```
public class UnidadesController : Controller
    {

    //Variable constante para definir el key de State en la Session
    const string State_KEY = "State";
    //Propiedad para extraer el listado de State de la Session simulando 
    acceso a la BD
    public List<Models.municipio> LstMunicipio
    {
        get { return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[State_KEY] != 
    null ? 

   (List<Models.municipio>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[State_KEY] 
  : new List<Models.municipio>(); }
        set { System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[State_KEY] = value; }
    }
    //En el constructor se da de alta todos los municipios que pueden ser 
    seleccionados
    public UnidadesController()
    {
        LstMunicipio = new List<Models.municipio>();
        LstMunicipio.AddRange(new List<Models.municipio>() {
                                                  new Models.municipio(){ 
     IdMunicipio =  1,  IdDepartamento = 1, Municipio = "Aguascalientes" },
                                                  new Models.municipio(){ 
     IdMunicipio =  2,  IdDepartamento = 1, Municipio = "Guadalajara" },

                                              });
        LstMunicipio.AddRange(new List<Models.municipio>() {
                                                   new Models.municipio(){ 
     IdMunicipio = 1 ,  IdDepartamento = 2, Municipio = "Ibaraki ken" },
                                                  new Models.municipio(){ 
    IdMunicipio = 2 ,  IdDepartamento = 2, Municipio = "Tokio" }
                                              });

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Todos los municipios se cargan para mostrarse en el dropdownlist
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>

    ///Metodo para obtener especificamente 1 departamento by Id valor 
    retornado como Json
    public JsonResult GetStateByIdDepartamento(int IdDepartamento)
    {
        return Json(new SelectList(LstMunicipio.Where(x => x.IdDepartamento 
   == IdDepartamento).ToList(), "IdMunicipio", "Municipio"));
    }
    public ActionResult Arope()
    {
        List<Models.departamento> lstDepartamento = new 
     List<Models.departamento>();
        lstDepartamento.Add(new Models.departamento()
        {
            IdDepartamento = 1,
            Departamento = "Antioquia"
        });
        lstDepartamento.Add(new Models.departamento()
        {
            IdDepartamento = 2,
            Departamento = "Cundinamarca"
        });
        //Se asigna la variable al viewbag
        ViewBag.IdDepartamento = new SelectList(lstDepartamento, 
    "IdDepartamento", "Departamento");
        return View();
      }
   }
  }
```

no se donde esta mal planteado la cuestion es que no logra realizar lo requerido

Comment: Intenta destruir el select2 antes de inicializar asi `if ($('#IdMunicipio').data('select2')) {
   $('#IdMunicipio').select2('destroy');
 }`

Comment: Segui como indicaste pero no hubo cambio en la ejecucion sigue sin funcionar